# elasticsearch speed comparison issue with sql

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I compare the speed of Sql with ElasticSearch. I have 1.5 million data. But sql query runs faster than elastic search. I don't understand the problem.
Why is the word like query coming faster in sql?

My code for Sql

```
public static List<Sales> GetAllRecords(string itemType)
        {
            List<Sales> salesReports = new List<Sales>();

            string sqlQuery = String.Format(@"SELECT * FROM dbo.Sales  where Region like '%{0}%'", itemType);
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(CONNECTION_STRING))
            {
                var result = connection.Query<Sales>(sqlQuery);
                foreach (var item in result)
                {
                    Sales global = new Sales()
                    {
                        Region = item.Region,
                        Country = item.Country,
                        Item_Type=item.Item_Type,
                        Order_Date=item.Order_Date,
                        Order_ID = item.Order_ID,
                        Order_Priority=item.Order_Priority,
                        Sales_Channel=item.Sales_Channel,
                        Ship_Date = item.Ship_Date,
                        Total_Cost=item.Total_Cost,
                        Total_Profit=item.Total_Profit,
                        Total_Revenue=item.Total_Revenue,
                        Units_Sold=item.Units_Sold,
                        Unit_Cost=item.Unit_Cost,
                        Unit_Price = item.Unit_Price
                    };
                    salesReports.Add(global);
                   
                }
                return result.ToList();
            }
        }
```

My code for ElasticSearch.
I search the data that I indexed before with elasticsearch here.

```
    public static List<Sales> ConfigureES(string inputText)
            {
                List<Sales> salesReports = new List<Sales>();
    
                // 1. Connection URL's elastic search
                var listOfUrls = new Uri[]
                {
                    // here we can set multple connectionn URL's...
                     new Uri("http://localhost:9200/")
                };
    
                StaticConnectionPool connPool = new StaticConnectionPool(listOfUrls);
                ConnectionSettings connSett = new ConnectionSettings(connPool);
                ElasticClient eClient = new ElasticClient(connSett);
    
                //  var see = eClient.DeleteIndex(INDEX_NAME);
    
                // check the connection health
                var checkClusterHealth = eClient.ClusterHealth();
                if (checkClusterHealth.ApiCall.Success && checkClusterHealth.IsValid)
                {
                    // 2. check the index exist or not 
                    var checkResult = eClient.IndexExists(INDEX_NAME);
                    if (!checkResult.Exists)
                    {
                        // Raise error to Index not avaliable
                    }
                    // Search particular text field 
                    var searchResponse = eClient.Search<Sales>(s => 
                   s.Index(INDEX_NAME).From(0).Size(5000).Scroll("10m")
                   .Query(q => q.Match(m => m.Field(f => f.Region).Query(inputText))));
    
                    //var results = eClient.Scroll<Salesreport>("10m", searchResponse.ScrollId);
                    while (searchResponse.Documents.Any())
                    {
                        var res = searchResponse.Documents;
                        var sds = res.Cast<Sales>();
                        salesReports.AddRange(sds);
                        searchResponse = eClient.Scroll<Sales>("10m", searchResponse.ScrollId);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // fail log the exception further use
                    var exception = checkClusterHealth.OriginalException.ToString();
                    var debugException = checkClusterHealth.DebugInformation.ToString();
                }
    
                return salesReports;
            }
```

where I index data to elasticsearch.

```
 public static string CONNECTION_STRING = string.Empty;
            public static string INDEX_NAME = "elastic";
            public static string INDEX_TYPE = "report4";
            private static ElasticClient eClient;
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                try
                {
                    // read the config file ...
                    var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(@"C:\Users\Celal\Desktop\ElasticSearch-master\ElasticSearch-master\ElasticSearchBGPJob\ElasticSearchBGPJob\ElasticSearchBGPJob")
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false)
                    .Build();
    
                    CONNECTION_STRING = configuration.GetSection("DefaultConnection").Value;
    
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(CONNECTION_STRING))
                        throw new ArgumentException("No connection string in appsettings.json");
    
                    // 1. Connection URL's elastic search
                    var listOfUrls =
                    // here we can set multple connectionn URL's...
                     new Uri("http://localhost:9200/");
                    ConnectionSettings connSett = new ConnectionSettings(listOfUrls);
                     eClient = new ElasticClient(connSett);
                    
                    //  var see = eClient.DeleteIndex(INDEX_NAME);
                    var createIndexDescriptor = new CreateIndexDescriptor(INDEX_NAME).Mappings(ms => ms.Map<Sales>(m => m.AutoMap()));
                    
                    // check the connection health
                    var checkClusterHealth = eClient.ClusterHealth();
                    if (checkClusterHealth.ApiCall.Success && checkClusterHealth.IsValid)
                    {
                        // 2. check the index exist or not 
                        var checkResult = eClient.IndexExists(INDEX_NAME);
                        if (!checkResult.Exists)
                        {
                            var createIndexResponse = eClient.CreateIndex(createIndexDescriptor);
                            if (createIndexResponse.ApiCall.Success && createIndexResponse.IsValid)
                            {
                                // index is created successfully....
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // fail log the exception further use
                                var exception = createIndexResponse.OriginalException.ToString();
                                var debugException = createIndexResponse.DebugInformation.ToString();
                            }
                        }
    
                        // 3. get the last documet id of index
                        var lastRecordResponse = eClient.Search<Sales>(s => s
                            .Index(INDEX_NAME)
                            .Type(INDEX_TYPE)
                            .From(0)
                            .Size(1).Sort(sr => sr.Descending(f => f.Order_ID)));
    
                        if (lastRecordResponse.ApiCall.Success && lastRecordResponse.IsValid)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Start " + DateTime.Now);
                            long salesRecordId = 0;
                            var listofrecords = new List<Sales>();
                            if (lastRecordResponse.Documents.Count >= 1)
                            {
                                var obj = lastRecordResponse.Documents;
                                foreach (var item in obj)
                                {
                                    salesRecordId = item.Order_ID;
                                }
    
                                listofrecords = GetAllRecords(salesRecordId);
    
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                listofrecords = GetAllRecords(salesRecordId);
                            }
    
                            Console.WriteLine("END " + DateTime.Now);
    
                            //   Insert the data into document format corresponding index...
                            if (listofrecords.Count > 0)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("===== START========= " + DateTime.Now);
                                BulkInsertData(listofrecords, eClient).Wait();
                                Console.WriteLine("===== END========= " + DateTime.Now);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // fail log the exception further use
                            var exception = lastRecordResponse.OriginalException.ToString();
                            var debugException = lastRecordResponse.DebugInformation.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // fail log the exception further use
                        var exception = checkClusterHealth.OriginalException.ToString();
                        var debugException = checkClusterHealth.DebugInformation.ToString();
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
            public static List<Sales> GetAllRecords(long LastSalesId)
            {
                List<Sales> salesReports = new List<Sales>();
                string sqlQuery = String.Format(@"SELECT * FROM dbo.Sales  where Order_ID > {0} ", LastSalesId);
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(CONNECTION_STRING))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection))
                    {
                        command.CommandTimeout = 1000;
                        using (SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
    
                            if (dataReader.HasRows)
                            {
                                while (dataReader.Read())
                                {
    
                                    Sales global = new Sales()
                                        {
                                            Order_ID=Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["Order_ID"]),
                                            Region=Convert.ToString(dataReader["Region"]),
                                            Country = Convert.ToString(dataReader["Country"]),
                                            Total_Cost = (decimal)Convert.ToDouble(dataReader["Total_Cost"]),
                                            Total_Revenue = Convert.ToString(dataReader["Total_Revenue"]),
                                            Item_Type = Convert.ToString(dataReader["Item_Type"])
                                        };
                                       
                                    salesReports.Add(global);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    connection.Close();
                }
    
                return salesReports;
            }
            static async Task BulkInsertData(List<Sales> ListofData, ElasticClient Eclient)
            {
                try
                {
                    var splitTheLargeList = ChunkBy(ListofData);
                    var test = splitTheLargeList.LastOrDefault();
    
                    foreach (var item in splitTheLargeList)
                    {
                        var bulkResponse = await Eclient.BulkAsync(b => b
                                            .Index(INDEX_NAME)
                                            // .Type(INDEX_TYPE)
                                            .IndexMany(item));
    
                        if (bulkResponse.ApiCall.Success && bulkResponse.IsValid)
                        {
                            // success fully inserted...
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // fail log the exception further use
                            var exception = bulkResponse.OriginalException.ToString();
                            var debugException = bulkResponse.DebugInformation.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.ToString());
                }
            }
    
            public static List<List<T>> ChunkBy<T>(List<T> source, int chunkSize = 1000)
            {
                return source
                    .Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Value = x })
                    .GroupBy(x => x.Index / chunkSize)
                    .Select(x => x.Select(v => v.Value).ToList())
                    .ToList();
            }
    
            public static IEnumerable<List<T>> SplitList<T>(List<T> ListofData, int listSize = 1000)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < ListofData.Count; i += listSize)
                {
                    yield return ListofData.GetRange(i, Math.Min(listSize, ListofData.Count - i));
                }
            }
```

Comment: Not that I'm able to tell why, but you haven't showed how you're indexing the data and neither how you are benchmarking the queries.

Comment: I added right now  @Xerillio

Comment: Perhaps I missed it, but there's no benchmarking here. For people to have a guess we need to see whether you are benchmarking the queries correctly and what the results show. There's currently no evidence that your claim is correct.